# Displaying Values to the rights side of each boxplot Plotly Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, boxplot

I have a dataset containing information about tasks, including the date they were performed, the task title, and the duration in hours. I want to visualize the boxplot statistics of task duration using boxplots in Plotly Express.

I have tried to create boxplots for, and while I can create the plots, I'm struggling with displaying the numerical values for mean, median, standard deviation, minimum, and maximum on the right side of each boxplot.

Here's my current code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Task_Title': ['Task 1', 'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 1', 'Task 3'],
    'Date': ['2023-09-24', '2023-09-24', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-08', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-24', '2023-09-24'],
    'mean': [1.0, 0.75, 1.25, 1.083333, 1.0, 0.75, 2.0, 1.125],
    'median': [1.0, 0.75, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75, 2.0, 1.125],
    'std': [None, None, 0.559017, 0.721688, None, None, None, 1.237437],
    'min': [1.0, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0, 0.75, 2.0, 0.25],
    'max': [1.0, 0.75, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75, 2.0, 2.0]
}

# Create a DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Ensure the 'Date' column is set as the datetime index
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Create box plots for daily statistics
fig = px.box(df, x='Date', y=['mean', 'median', 'std', 'min', 'max'],
             title='Combined Daily Duration Statistics',
             labels={'Date': 'Statistics'})
fig.update_traces(boxpoints='all', jitter=0.3, pointpos=-1.8)
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(
    title='Combined Daily Duration Statistics',
    xaxis=dict(title='Statistics'),
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

How can I modify this code to display the numerical data values (mean, median, std, min, max) on the right side of each boxplot?

---

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-save-labels-on-plotly-box-plot-instead-of-it-disappearing-when-not-hovering-on-it/54637/2) in the plolty community, answered with string annotations. I think this will help you.